# What does shit mean in the expression "doesn't take shit from anyone?"

Tags: idioms

Is shit in that idiom something unjustified or something justified? Like shit seems to indicate that it's not something that was deserved. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lorel commented:

> It refers to bad or disrespectful treatment. Usually undeserved.

Comment: Come up with your own answer, your own explanation.

Comment: @MaulikV It is perfectly reasonable to take a valid comment and turn it into an answer. I was simply giving credit for relocating a comment that should have been an answer in the first place. https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4592/should-i-cite-someone-elses-comment-in-my-answer

Comment: In that case, you could have simply put another comment under the 'answer comment' asking the OP to put it as an answer. Anyway, I did nothing to this answer being a moderator.